# SPSS - PROCESS macro v4.2 doesn't output conditional effects of the focal predictor

Tags: statistics, spss, process-macro

When moderation analysis is done using the PROCESS macro v4.2 beta, the output is not full. "Output conditional effects of the focal predictor at values of the moderator" is missing.

The required output must show this part too:
[image: Required part of the output]

Actual output:
[image: Actual output]

The settings that I used:
[image: Settings Part 1]

[image: Settings Part 2 - Options]

I tried running with a different version of the macro, but the website with PROCESS macro does not allow me to download older versions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ProcessMacro website (http://processmacro.org/faq.html), the conditional effects only show by default when the p-value is less than or equal to 0.10.

From your output, the interaction p-value is 0.3261 and that is why the conditional effects will not be displayed.

According to the documentation, the default can be overridden by using the intprobe option.

"Question: Why isn't PROCESS producing conditional effects of a focal predictor or showing Johnson-Neyman output when I ask for it?

Answer:  In version 3 and later, PROCESS produces information relevant to probing an interaction only when the corresponding interaction has a p-value of 0.10 or less.  This is the default but, it can be changed to a larger or smaller value using the intprobe option. See the documentation."